# What's the integration of $e^{x \sin x}?$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am a beginner at integration. I sometimes write a random function and try to calculate the integral of that function. So, I tried with $e^{x\sin x}$.

Boy, it's not like others. I googled for it and didn't find anything.

Any hint on this regard? If you just point out, what new method or stuffs, I have to learn about solving it, it will do.

Comment: $\int e^{x \sin x} dx$ doesn't seem to have a closed form [as WolfrmaAlpha says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5Bx+*+Sin%5Bx%5D%5D,x%5D)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, random functions will have no closed-form antiderivative.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by rule of thumb? Besides, random functions that I sometimes write do have indefinite integral.

Comment: I think by random @YvesDaoust means that if you just start randomly composing elementary functions together you likely won't have a closed-form.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thumb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function does not have a primitive in terms of elementary functions i.e. you are not supposed to be able to integrate that.

Another example would be

$$\int e^{-x^2} dx$$

Whose primitive (except for a scaling factor) is called the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), *erf*.

You can calculate the integrals numerically but you can't write its primitive.

Comment: How can we know that a certain function doesn't have a primitive? Is there any method?

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution in terms of standard mathematics so you won't be able to find a "solution". If you try to calculate the definite integral you can use numerics, but no analytical solution can be found.

Hint: Use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20e%5E%7Bx%20sin(x)%7D) to calc such integrals

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure, but there's a good chance that this function's integral is *not* an elementary function, meaning that it cannot be written as a product, sum, and compositum of polynomials, exponential functions, trigonometric functions and the like.

The best known example of this is the function $e^{x^2}$, but in general, if you randomly think of a compositum of elementary functions, there's a high chance it doesn't have an elementary integral.

Comment: $e^{-x^2}$ is even better known, I think ...